# Have we observed time dilation on quickly-vibrating or very hot objects?

Tags: time-dilation, radioactivity

The common sci-fi example of time dilation would involve a futuristic spacecraft going on a one-year mission, returning to Earth 100 years later.

We can imagine this happening on a smaller scale, too. We could imagine an object running back and forth down a hallway to experience time dilation. Taken to the limit, we could imagine an object vibrating at a very high frequency to experience time dilation. Because heat is just the motion of particles within a body, we could also imagine heat to cause time dilation.

Whether or not this is *plausible* has been asked before ( [Could fast vibrations cause us to travel forward in time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91635/could-fast-vibrations-cause-us-to-travel-forward-in-time) ).

What I'm wondering is, has this ever been observed experimentally, even if with a very small effect? I could imagine this is possible with sensitive equipment and a sample of a radioactive material with a known half-life.

Comment: Time dilation is often considered when an object moves freely in an inertial frame. Vibration is more like the twin paradox where one twin is at rest an an inertial frame, and the other moves away and then changes direction and moves back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Here is why:

For time dilation effects to start becoming obvious, the moving object must have a velocity of order ~0.5c where c is the speed of light. There is no way available to us to run material objects back and forth in your hallway anywhere near fast enough to "get relativistic", even by heating them super-hot with gas torches or whatnot.

The closest we can imagine to this condition is by compressing electrons so intensely that the volume they occupy while vibrating is so reduced that the uncertainty principle forces their velocities to approach the speed of light. This can only be accomplished in the cores of supermassive stars, not your hallway.

Under those conditions, the electrons start pushing back really, really hard and strongly resist any further compression. That extra pushback "stiffens" the so-called *equation of state* for the electron cloud, which if we could actually measure it would furnish evidence of relativistic effects occurring on the scale of individual electrons within the cloud.